# How can I load a constant value into the floating point register st0?

Tags: assembly, x87, cheat-engine

I believe the correct way to do this is the following:

```
const1:     dq  1.2345
...
     fld    const1
```

However, I'm using Cheat Engine to reverse engineer a game (so I can understand it better). And it shows the following error:

[image: cheat engine showing the constant value cannot be loaded]

Can someone please tell me what's wrong here? Ideally I would like the second command to be:

```
fstp dword [esi+ 3C]
```

But before I do this I need to load 93.5 value into the st(0) register. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Consult cheat engine documentation on how to initialize float constants. If all else fails and you know how to initialize data bytes then convert your value. That may in fact be the simplest solution, you can replace the whole thing with just `mov dword [esi+3C], 0; mov dword [esi+40],  0x40576000`. No constant in memory, `fld` or `fstp` needed. It's unclear why you have two `fstp` since the first one pops the value from the stack.

Comment: @Jester Sorry about the ambiguity and thanks for bringing this up! I like your idea of using a simple mov statement for this. The first memory label "newmem" is where our code execution is going to start from. This includes 3 new lines that I have written (val, fld and fstp). At this point our health is stored in register st(0) and then these 3 instructions get executed (well 1 label + 2 instructions). Once my code gets executed I want to have a large value in st(0) and the memory address. Everything after this (the label "code") is the pre-existing code (the original code of the game).

Comment: If you want the same value in `st0` and in memory you can reload it using `fld dword [esi+3C]`.

Comment: Besides the syntax error, you have data and code next to each other.  If execution jumps to `newmem:`, the bytes of the `double` 93.5 will be decoded as instructions.

Comment: @Jester This is brilliant! Would you mind adding both of your points as an answer so that I can select it and finish off this question?

Comment: @PeterCordes I followed the tutorial given here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Floating_Point and also in other places given on stackoverflow. For some reason nobody every provides a value to fld instruction. Instead all tutorials point to a "memory label". Just like you mention, even I thought that it would get read as an instruction but after seeing all these tutorials online I figured that it might be able to make out the difference. What do you suggest is the proper way to have the data separated from the code?

Comment: Put your `const1:     dq  1.2345` somewhere else, like at the bottom of your file after your code.  (Preferably in `section .data`, or `section .rdata` for read-only data).  The first example from the page you linked  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Floating_Point#Examples shows doing that (with the data before the code, but order within the source file doesn't actually matter when it's in a different section.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a series of syntax related errors causing your problem.

"this instruction cannot be compiled"
You're putting data in a code section.  Define your variable outside of the newmem block and inside of a separate memory block.  You're trying to define a memory block with "val:" but you haven't allocated that memory.  You also can't reference it without registering a symbol.

To define a regular float you use a 4 byte variable not a 8 byte variable so you use "dd" not "dq", secondly you need to "cast" it to a float.

Your instruction you want to push a float onto the FPU stack is written like so:
fld dword ptr [val]

Create the injection template as you have done previously and then insert this code at the top and continue what you were doing, it has everything I have noted in the answer and I tested it working:

```
alloc(newmem,2048)
label(returnhere)
label(originalcode)
label(exit)

alloc(val,8)

val:
dd (float)93.5

registersymbol(val)

newmem:
fld dword ptr [val]
```

Keep in mind you will need to use the rest of the generated template, this is just the code to fix the errors seen in your question.

Comment: @PeterCordes that little snippet at the top of the question is a random copy and paste from some guide.  The code I posted is Cheat Engine scripting syntax.  Cheat Engine does not accept "fldl", just tried it

Comment: @PeterCordes I believe that was a typo. The real code doesn't have fldl, as shown in the screenshot. Sorry about the confusion. I've updated it now.

Comment: @Mugen: This is why you *always* copy/paste code into SO for debugging questions :/  Your example is still missing square-brackets or a size specifier.  That would work in *some* assemblers, like MASM, but be invalid in others like NASM or GAS, where the declaration doesn't imply a size for other instructions using it.  Again, IDK whether your example outside the screenshot is even close to valid Cheat Engine syntax.

Comment: @PeterCordes I understand that you're trying to help but I feel that you've made your point about "copy-pasting" already. Yes, I do _always_ perform a copy/paste. I _love_ copy/pasting for most occasions. However, there is NO CODE to copy/paste from. If there were then I would just copy/paste the solution. I don't know floating point assembly syntax properly and I"m still learning it. The whole point of the example was to give an idea of what I'm trying to achieve. If you notice there is also the ellipsis. The code won't execute as long as the ellipsis are present too, isn't it? It's there...

Comment: ... to bring the focus into the area where I need help. And I find your behavior close to bullying. While I'm trying to figure out the basics of Floating point assembly language, you're expecting me to know about MASM, NASM and GAS. I'm here to learn but I certainly don't appreciate the manner in which you're repeatedly hammering me for not knowing about the very area on which I raised the question.